# Create a list of regular expression matches from XML document in R

Tags: r, xml, expression

I would like to create a list of all the matches of a regular expression that can be found in an XML document using R. I have retrieved the XML document using:

XMLdocument <- read_xml("https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokumente/Vfgh/JFT_20191212_19G00164_00/JFT_20191212_19G00164_00.xml")

I am interested in all matches of GXXXX/YYYY, with G being the string "G", XXXX being a number between 1 and 9999 and YYYY being a a number between 1 and 9999, in the nodes "absatz" with ct="begruendung".

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's easier for folks to help you debug your code than for us to come up with it from scratch

Comment: Has my answer below helped you @user12276485?

Comment: Thank you very much @meenaparam. Your answer has help me.

Comment: Glad it helped @user12276485. Please can you accept my answer below so the question is marked as complete?

Comment: Done. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to get what you're after. You can modify this answer if there is also text matching your target pattern in other parts of the XML document.

```r
library(xml2)
library(stringr)

# read in the XML doc
xmldoc <- as_list(read_xml("https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokumente/Vfgh/JFT_20191212_19G00164_00/JFT_20191212_19G00164_00.xml"))

# extract all the "absatz" elements as these seem to hold the relevant text
absatz <- lapply(1:length(xmldoc$risdok$nutzdaten$abschnitt), 
                 function(x){
                     xmldoc$risdok$nutzdaten$abschnitt[x]$absatz[[1]]
                     })

# extract all the "cts" elements
cts <- lapply(1:length(xmldoc$risdok$nutzdaten$abschnitt), 
             function(x){
                 attributes(xmldoc$risdok$nutzdaten$abschnitt[x]$absatz)$ct
             })

# flatten the cts to get a character vector
cts <- unlist(cts)

# find the indices of the cts which equal "begruendung"
begs_idx <- grep(pattern = "begruendung", x = cts)

# subset the absatz list using the begruendung indices
absatz_bg <- absatz[begs_idx]

# remove null items in the absatz_bg list
names(absatz_bg) <- seq_along(absatz_bg)
absatz_bg[sapply(absatz_bg, is.null)] <- NULL

# flatten the list to get a character vector
flat_absatz_bg <- unlist(absatz_bg)

# find instances of the pattern GXXXX/YYYY,
output <- flat_absatz_bg %>% str_extract(pattern = "G\\d+/\\d+")

# remove the NAs
gs <- output[!is.na(output)]

# look at the result
gs
#>  [1] "G164/2019" "G415/2017" "G136/2017" "G136/2017" "G136/2017" "G136/2017"
#>  [7] "G156/2018" "G136/207"  "G136/2017" "G308/2018" "G179/2015" "G156/2018"
#> [13] "G415/2017"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>